# Postgresql using date interval and SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I have a table with 3 columns - a timestamp, a real, and a string.  The String columns holds various time frequency values (like Minutes, Hours, Days).  I want to take the value in my timestamp column and add to it the values in the other columns.  For example I'd like to do something like

```
select timestamp '2015-04-20 01:00' + interval '2 hours'
```

if I had a table with the following columns and values

```
action_start_time   rate  frequency
2015-04-20 01:00    2     hours
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following query to convert  `rate` and `frequency` columns to ***interval***

```
select format('%s %s',rate,frequency)::interval
from actions
```

and then get the exact timestamp just by adding the interval with `action_start_time` *column*

```
select action_start_time + format('%s %s',rate,frequency)::interval my_timestamp
from actions
```

[**demo-sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4bcd9/1)

Comment: All good choices provided here.  Thanks.  I went with this option as it seems to be straightforward enough.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
SELECT action_start_time + rate * ('1'|| frequency)::interval
```

The all trick is in a using multiplication of some interval value:

```
postgres=# select 3 * interval '1 hour';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ 03:00:00 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

You can simply create any interval value without necessity to manipulate with strings. Surely, should be better, if your column `frequency` is native PostgreSQL `interval` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
select action_start_time + (rate::varchar||' '||frequency)::interval
```

Start with the action_start_time then take the rate (cast to a character) and append a space and then the frequency to achieve a string like '1 hours' or '3 days' etc..  then cast that string to an interval and add that to the original action_start_time